# Change image on scroll JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Essentially im trying to make a basic function that flicks through images on scroll.

I have everything in jsfiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/JUST_RJ/6zb37d94/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#c1").fadeIn(0);
    console.log()

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var pos = $(document).scrollTop();
      if (pos < 200) {
        hideAll("c1");
        $("#c1").fadeIn(0);
      }
      if (pos > 200 && pos < 400) {
        hideAll("c2");
        $("#c2").fadeIn(0);
      }
        if (pos > 400 && pos < 600) {
        hideAll("c3");
        $("#c3").fadeIn(0);
      }


    });

    function hideAll(exceptMe) {
      $(".image").each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == exceptMe) return;
        $(this).fadeOut(0);
      });
    }


});
```

Right now I have it working, although I think it will get complicated when adding more images.
I want to keep the image src listed in the html so its easy to add a new image and to also manually select the image size.

Im wondering if the JS part can be simplified to do two things…

1. Get the scroll height and automatically add a preset value (200) to flick to the next image.

Currently the scroll amount to change the image has to be added manually, like so...

- Once scroll is at 200 change to image 2
- Show image 2 at 200 > 600
- Once scroll is at 600 change to image 3
- etc

This would make each image show for a scroll of 200 and then flick to the next image without manually having to add the scroll amount and distance from the previous image each time.

2. Is there a way the code can be simplified so in the js, a new image doesn’t need to be added with an id each time? Perhaps there is a way it can count the amount of images in the html with the class “image” and then automatically add an id number which adds 1 to the previous id?

Something like..

- Count amount of images in html with the class “image”
- Store number (in this case 3)
- Create #c1
- Create #c2
- Create #c3
- Show #c1 for a scroll of 200
- Show #c2 for a scroll of 200
- Etc

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you need

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/9tqcdp61/

calculate the element in the range of `imgSpaces`  in this example it's  200  using this:

`"#c" + (Math.round(pos / imgSpace) + 1)`

Comment: Kanyan this is looking great, thanks! is there a way so the last image doesnt disappear at the bottom of the page? It just stays on the last image?

Comment: check now   it calculates the height of the body dynamically depending on the number of images in html

Comment: @ Rkv88 - Kanyan thanks! This is working well. It seems I can adjust the space between images to make sure the last image always shows. 

Also, is there a way it can swap to the next image on scroll and onclick?

Comment: I would recommend looking into IntersectionObserver as another way to create this functionality (not jQuery). 
The problem with the different example shown here is that you will have a bloadet website with using `document.addeventListener("scroll"...)` **especially if you need to scale this functionality!**

With IntersectionObserver if you observer for example an image, it will only be called when the image is in the viewport or when it is leaving it. With that and `position: sticky` you will be able to create change image on scroll.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/fd69ensv/1/

Add all the images to an array in JS
Use `Math.floor()` to round down `x / 200` - This will give you the index of the image in your array.
Update the `img src` on scroll.

Comment: this works, although anyway to keep the list of images in the html?

Comment: Sure,

https://jsfiddle.net/65jvqxdc/2/

Same concept, just interpolate the number of the `id` you need.